# Primefaces ajax not working update on field datatable

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have problem with "" component in my application. I have a datatable with 2 fields editable first is an inputtext and second field is a dateInput.

Inside fields I put  to update value in list but when submit it to bean not updated the values.

Below is my page.xhtml and bean.

```
<p:dialog id="modalNovosParametrosRecesso" header="Salvar Novos Parâmetros de Estagiário"
                  widgetVar="widgetvarNovoParametro" 
                  draggable="true" resizable="false" 
                  closable="false" modal="true" width="630">

               <h:outputText styleClass="modalRecessoAuto" value="#{msg.MN064}" escape="false" />

              <br />   
             <h:panelGroup>
                <br />
                <p:dataTable id="tableRegRecessoAuto" var="recessoAuto"
                    value="#{parametroEstagiarioMB.visao.listaOcorrenciaRegistroRecesso}"
                    styleClass="hide-column-names" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" >

                    <p:column style="width:98px;">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{rowIndex+1}º Recesso de " style="color: #0039BA" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{recessoAuto.diasRecesso}" size="2">
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update=":frmFiltro:tableRegRecessoAuto" ignoreAutoUpdate="true"    global="false" />
                        </p:inputText>

                        <h:outputLabel value="dia(s) começando em " style="color: #0039BA" />
                        <p:inputMask value="#{recessoAuto.dtInicioOcorrencia}"  mask="99/99/9999" size="10">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="pt_BR" />
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update=":frmFiltro:tableRegRecessoAuto" ignoreAutoUpdate="true"    global="false"/>                                
                        </p:inputMask>

                        <h:outputLabel value=" e finalizando em " style="color: #0039BA; margin-left: 5px;"/>
                        <h:outputLabel id="dtLbl1" value="#{recessoAuto.dtFimOcorrencia}"   style="color: #0039BA; margin-left: 5px;" >
                           <f:convertDateTime for="dtLbl1" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="pt_BR"/>
                        </h:outputLabel>
                    </p:column>
```

-->

```
            <div style="padding-left: 170px;">



                <p:commandLink styleClass="btnLaranja marginTop"
                               ignoreAutoUpdate="true" global="false" ajax="false" action="#{parametroEstagiarioMB.salvarRecessoPrimeiraParametrizacao()}"
                               update=":frmFiltro:tableRegRecessoAuto">
                    <span>Confirmar</span>
                </p:commandLink>                    

                <p:commandLink styleClass="btnLaranja marginTop"
                                id="btnCancelarRecessoAuto"
                                oncomplete="PF('widgetvarNovoParametro').hide();"
                                ignoreAutoUpdate="true" global="false" actionListener="#{parametroEstagiarioMB.cancelar}">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                    target="#{parametroEstagiarioMB.visao.exibirModal}"
                                    value="#{false}" />                                 
                                <span>Cancelar</span>
                </p:commandLink>

                <p:commandLink styleClass="btnLaranja marginTop"
                               id="btnVerRegrasAuto"
                               oncomplete="PF('widgetvarModalRegras').show();"
                               ignoreAutoUpdate="true" global="false">
                               <span>Regras</span>
                </p:commandLink>
            </div>  

        </p:dialog>
```

My Bean:

```
public void salvarRecessoPrimeiraParametrizacao(){

    int count = 0;      

    final DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .findComponent(":frmFiltro:tableRegRecessoAuto");

    List<OcorrenciaPonto> teste = new ArrayList<OcorrenciaPonto>();

    for(OcorrenciaPonto c : (List<OcorrenciaPonto>) dataTable.getValue()){
        teste.add(c);
        count+=1;
    }}
```

datatable.getValues() not get new values and yes old values that displayed in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using getters and setters correctly?

Have you tried to use `immediate="true"` on input fields?

Answer (score -3):

I saw you are using `<p:ajax>` .
 I had some troubles with this. 
Maybe, if you change to `**<f:ajax>**` this must works so well.

Comment: Did you try  use the <f:ajax> ?

Comment: Very bad unthoughtful answer. If you answer this way, I'm pretty sure the switch from p tof ajax was a workaround for a more fundamental problem